# How to perform slope using PostGIS?

Tags: slope, postgis-raster

I want to perform Slope using PostGIS. I used this query but I got a strange result unit:

```
create table my_slope as
SELECT ST_Slope(rast,1,'32BF','PERCENT',1, false) as slope
FROM my_raster
```

I wonder know why I got this strange result.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

I must apply st_union then st_transform (to reproject the raster) for 4326 to 2154

```
create table my_slope as
SELECT ST_Slope(st_transform(st_union(rast),2154),1,'32BF','PERCENT',1, false) as slope
FROM my_raster
```